# Using cURL with large data files

Tags: rest, curl, memory

I have this cURL command to run:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json"
-u "{username}":"{password}" 
"https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/retrieve-and-rank/api/v1/solr_clusters/{solr_cluster_id}/solr/example_collection/update" 
--data-binary @./data.json
```

Where `data.json` is a 60 GB file. I ran it, and my computer bluescreened after reaching 100% memory usage.  I assume by that that cURL reads the entire file into memory before sending it.

Obviously, with 16GB of RAM I won't be able to do that.  So, my question is: is there a way to use cURL where I could send a huge file like that?  And if not, is there an alternative way to accomplish the same thing that cURL does?

Comment: Piotr's suggestion is for downloads, so it won't work directly. But the principle is good enough: Split your JSON into smaller chunks and send them one at a time. You will need to split so that each chunk is valid JSON in itself.